# Creating a UI/writing HTML from a JSON file

Tags: html, json, node.js, user-interface, lighthouse

I have a really long, unwieldy, unformatted JSON file generated by Lighthouse (a tool that conducts page load time analysis- so this file has the results of the tests). In order to make it formatted to be readable by people, I need to apparently create a UI around this file. My problem is that I'm not sure how to begin working on it.

I've read about something like creating HTML from JSON objects, I think I'd like to try that to just display all the information from the tests in the browser right now... But where would I write that? I have one Node.js file right now, which is running the tests and using `JSON.stringify()` to stick the JSON'd results into a file. Can I generate the HTML right after I create the JSON? (And the main question- how would I create HTML from a JSON file?)

I'm just starting out with Node and JSON, any tips are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can create HTML from a JSON file.

Here's a simple example done with jQuery, first creating an array of all of the elements, and then using **[`.join("")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** to parse them. Once parse, they can simply be appended anywhere in the DOM:

```js
var json_file = {
  "one": "Hi there",
  "two": "Another item",
  "three": "Third item"
}

var items = [];

$.each(json_file, function(key, val) {
  items.push("<li id='" + key + "'>" + val + "</li>");
});

$("<ul/>", {
  "class": "json-list",
  html: items.join("")
}).appendTo("body");

// Sample extension showcasing manipulation of inserted HTML
$(".json-list #two").css('color', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Obviously, the more complicated your JSON (and desired HTML structure), the more complicated the method of parsing the JSON is going to be.

A templating engine would make your job significantly easier,
 and there and **hunderds** of these. Some of the more popular ones are:

- [**EJS**](http://embeddedjs.com/)
- [**jQuery.dForm**](http://daffl.github.com/jquery.dform/#types/add-your-own)
- [**JQuote2**](http://aefxx.com/api/jqote2-reference/)
- [**JSON Template**](http://json-template.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/Introducing-JSON-Template.html)
- [**JTemplates**](http://jtemplates.tpython.com/)
- [**Mustache**](http://mustache.github.com/)
- [**PURE**](http://beebole.com/pure/)
- [**Tempo**](http://tempojs.com/)

Hope this helps! :)

Comment: It looks to me like no matter whether I use a templating engine or not, there is some manual aspect to formatting that HTML/specifying what info I need from the JSON file. This file is probably one million lines, and it is not formatted at all (it's one huge block of text in textedit, and one single very long line when I open it in sublime text). I'm thinking I have to get my test results into a non-JSON file and figure out another way to display them.

Comment: Well, I'm digging through that monster of a file right now for the names of the elements I need to display (and I'm using Mustache). I started out with something like the example you gave above, but now I've switched to the creation and editing of a package.json file. Specifically, I'm editing the `script` so I can generate a template using a cli command.